# Adding new levels to p5 game

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have created a basic p5.js bubble game, where I eat smaller bubbles to grow bigger and avoid bigger bubbles. Now I want to add new levels with more, faster enemies and to start the next level only when I click a button. I have tried a lot of different things, but encounter a new set of problems every time I try something.

So what would be the smartest way to add new levels to a p5.js game?

```
var player;
var enemy;

var enemies;
var walls;

var topWall;
var rightWall;
var bottomWall;
var leftWall;

var gameOver = false;
var win = false;

var numberOfEnemies = 10;


function setup() {

    createCanvas(700, 600);

    enemies = new Group();
    walls = new Group();

    function createWall(name,x,y,width,height){
        name = createSprite(x, y, width, height);
        name.shapeColor = color(0,255,0);
        name.immovable = true;
        walls.add(name);
    }
    createWall("topWall", 0, 0, width*2, 20);
    createWall("rightWall", width, height, 20, height*2);
    createWall("bottomWall", 0, height, width*2, 20);
    createWall("leftWall", 0, 0, 20, height*2);

    function createEnemy(x,y,size){
        enemy = createSprite(x,y,size,size);
        enemy.shapeColor = color(255,0,0);
        enemies.add(enemy);

        enemy.draw = function(){
            fill(255,0,255);
            ellipse(0,0,size,size);
        }
    }

    /* Create 10 enemies */
    for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        createEnemy( Math.floor(random(640)), Math.floor(random(480)), 10*i );
    }
    player = createSprite(0,0,40,40);

    if(win){
        level++;
    }
}


function draw() {
    background(0);
    noStroke();

    drawSprites();

    enemies.bounce(enemies);
    enemies.bounce(walls);

    for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
        enemies[i].attractionPoint(0.01, mouseX, mouseY);
        enemies[i].maxSpeed = 2;
    }

    player.position.x = mouseX;
    player.position.y = mouseY;

    for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
        if(player.overlap(enemies[i])){
            if(player.width > enemies[i].width){
                indexOfEaten = enemies.indexOf(enemies[i]);
                console.log(indexOfEaten);
                eatOrBeEaten(indexOfEaten);
                player.width = player.width + 10;
                player.height = player.height + 10;
            }else{
                console.log("dead");
                player.remove();
                gameOver = true;
            }
        }
    }

    function eatOrBeEaten(index){
        enemies[index].remove();
        numberOfEnemies--;
        console.log("number of enemies"+numberOfEnemies);
        if(numberOfEnemies == 0){
            win = true;
        }
    }

    player.draw = function(){
        fill(0,0,255);
        ellipse(0,0,player.width,player.height);
    }

    if(gameOver){
        textSize(65);
        textAlign(CENTER);
        fill(255, 255, 255);
        text('GAME OVER', width/2, height/2);
    }

    if(win){ 
        textSize(60);
        textAlign(CENTER);
        fill(255, 255, 255);
        text("LEVEL COMPLETED.", width/2, height/2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Could you inform me on what the error you encounter is. Will save me a ton of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So what would be the smartest way to add new levels to a p5.js game?

There isn't just one smartest way to do this. Like many things in programming, there are about a million different ways to do this. That's one of the great things about programming, but it's also frustrating when you're just trying to figure out how to proceed. It also makes questions like this hard to answer.

The most straightforward approach would be to use a `level` variable that keeps track of which level you're currently on. Then inside the `draw()` function, you'd use a series of `if` statements that check the level and draw it. Something like this:

```
function draw(){
  if(level == 1){
    // draw level 1
  }
  else if(level == 2){
    // draw level 2
  }
}
```

Another approach would be to use objects that represent a particular level. Then store them in something like an array and use that to draw the current level. Something like this:

```
function draw(){
  levels[level].drawLevel();
}
```

I'd also recommend you take a step back and start with something simpler. Create a "game" that draws the current level to the screen and advances to the next level when the user clicks the mouse. Get that working perfectly before you try to add in your actual game logic.